# Typescript error when using useImperativeHandle alongside TextInput

Tags: typescript, react-native, hook

I'm trying to convert [ReactNative official example](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) for `useImperativeHandle` with TypeScript

- **original**:

```
function FancyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} ... />;
}
FancyInput = forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

- **with TypeScript**:

```
import React, { ReactElement, Ref, useRef, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

interface FancyInputProps {
  name: string;
}

const FancyInput = (props: FancyInputProps, ref: Ref<TextInput>): ReactElement => {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    },
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
};

export default forwardRef(FancyInput);
```

But `focus` is highlighted by my IDE with the following error message:

> Type '{ focus: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from
> type 'TextInput': isFocused, clear, measure, measureInWindow, and 18
> more.

It's because `TextInput` have indeed other properties, but I want to only add one (`focus`), no rewrite all the others properties.

I have a feeling I'm not that far, any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you try const inputRef = useRef<Partial<TextInput>>(null);> ?

Comment: @ABOS thank you sir :) it does work ! I'll let you answer if you need the point otherwise I will create my own answer, it is really up to you. I didn't knew the existence of Partial.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @ABOS for pointing out the existence of [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) in TypeScript

Final solution being:

```
import React, { ReactElement, Ref, useRef, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

interface FrancyInputProps {
  name: string;
}

const FancyInput = (props: FrancyInputProps, ref: Ref<Partial<TextInput>>): ReactElement => {
  const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef?.current?.focus();
    },
  }));
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
};

export default forwardRef(FancyInput);
```